# Homotopy direct limit

Tags: homotopy-theory

Suppose that $X$ is the homotopy direct limit of $\{X_i\}$. If each $X_i$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex, then is $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex?

Comment: Obviously not true if you require finite CW complexes.  Are you letting your CW complexes have infinitely many cells?  Arbitrarily high dimension?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is because the construction of the homotopy colimit over CW-complexes involves taking the geometric realization of a particular coend of simplicial sets.  The geometric realization of any simplicial set always has the homotopy type of a CW-complex.